# Does there has a suggestion MIPS tool chain version for Cobalt?

Tags: cobalt

I would like to know if there has suggestion MIPS toolchain version for Cobalt.
  Or after which MIPS version is suitable for compiling source code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Cobalt is know to build successfully for MIPS targets with GCC 4.9.

That said, it should be possible to build Cobalt with any C++03-compliant toolchain.